# What does ってことか？ mean?

Tags: meaning

In this sentence:

> つまりアレだ、俺が自らあのばーさんとこまでの道を作り出しちまったってことか？

I guess it's something like:

> It's that thing right?  I created a path that leads to that old hag?

What part would ってことか represent here?

Comment: 「アレだ」は filler word みたいなものです。これが参考になるかも→ http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/606/9831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **つまり**アレだ、俺が[自]{みずか}らあのばーさんとこまでの道を作り出しちまった**ってことか**？

(つまり)～～ってことか means (つまり)～～ということか, "(So,) does it mean...?"   (Compare: 「～ってことだ」=「～ということだ」= "That means...")

For more examples, see [Weblio 例文集「つまり ということですか」](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8A+%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)