# Meaning of これってアレ

Tags: grammar

I have some difficulty understanding this grammar structure.

The context is

> いやにみられてるんですけど。**これってアレ**よ、きっと私から滲{にじ}み出る神オーラで。。。
>
> I don't like the way they're looking at me. I know ! It's the goddess
> aura I exude ...

って probably stands for というのは、アレ＝あれ, but it does not seem to make sense to have これ and あれ at the same time.

I feel I am missing something...

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/606/9831

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. 「これってあれ」 just means 「これというのはあれ」. It's just filler words. Like in English, you could say things like "This is, you know..." when you can't find the words to properly express your thoughts. A literal translation might be "This is, you know, that". So maybe a more natural translation for your sentence would be:

> これってあれよ、きっと私から滲み出る神オーラで。。。
> This must be because of, you know, the godly aura I'm exuding...