# What does this sentence means with areka/あれか at the start?

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, expressions, japanese-to-english

**When reading, I met with a sentence with areka/あれか at the beginning and it's hard for me to understand. Much thanks if anyone can help me understand it correctly (in case I was wrong ).**

**あれか。貴様は死人で、いわゆる幽霊とかいう奴か。**

Context : MC has been transported to another world and a girl saw him fall down from the sky. Then she brought him back to her house while he's still unconscious. After 1 week, MC woke up and the girl said he had slept for 1 entire week, and started to asking him a lot of questions since this is her 1st time to see a man fall down from the sky.

Girl「貴様、一週間眠りっぱなしだったぞ？壮健なのか？まぁそれだけ騒げれば壮健だろうが」

Girl「いやそんなことより貴様に聞きたいことがある。いったいどうやって天から落ちてきた？いや、そもそもどうやって天に昇った？」

Girl「**あれか。貴様は死人で、いわゆる幽霊とかいう奴か。**
いや幽霊は触れないと聞くが、貴様はちゃんと触れるな。では違うか」
**(my guess but not sure: "Oh I know. You're like a corpse when I found you, so you're like a ghost right ?")**

Answer (score 2):

In terms of translation, I think あれか translates to *Ah, I see* or *Aha* in most cases.

Explaining how is a bit difficult, but it means of course *that* and it indicates that the speaker comes to *see* the connection between the topic under discussion (in this case, the interlocutor) and *that* (in this case, a ghost).

Thus it says *Aha, you are a dead man and a so-called ghost, right?*.

Answer (score 2):

This type of あれ (often written as アレ in katakana) has been discussed in the following questions.

- [Meaning of 〜あれだ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/606/5010)
- [Meaning of これってアレ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83182/5010)
- [Understanding だった的なアレ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83976/5010)

So this あれ ("that") vaguely refers to an idea that should be understood without explaining it in detail ("*that* idea", "*that* thing you know", "*that* thingy", "you-know-what"). Here, あれ refers to the generic idea of ghosts, what people usually understand as so-called ghosts. This type of あれ is also written as [例の](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BE%8B%E3%81%AE)あれ.

So literally:

> あれか。
> [Is this] *that thing* (we know)?
> [Could it be] *that one*?
> [So this is...] you know what.